# jQuery - animate from transparent to color without white flash?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I need to animate from transparent to coloured but when I do I get a white flash. I assume this is because there is no base colour to animate from. How do I get around this?

```
$('#nav a').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'background-color' : $(this).attr('data-background'),
        'color' : $(this).attr('data-rollover')
    }, 900);
});

<a style="color:#ffff00; " data-background="#000066" data-color="#ffff00" data-rollover="#000000" href="index.php?p=1" ><span >Home</span></a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Animate the `opacity` instead of the `background-color` property.

Answer (score 1):

Alex is right. you have do it with `opacity`. You can try this:

```
$('#nav a').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'opacity': 0
    },
    1,
    function() {
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': $(this).attr('data-rollover'),
            'color': $(this).attr('data-color')
        }).animate({
            'opacity': 1
        },
        900);
    });
});
```

Comment: @John Smith Hi friend, as much I know `background-color` or `color` cant be animated.

Comment: You need the *colors* plugin to animate colours.